# Decimal.Parse various strings

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, format

Hello I might have strings for example `"1,1"` or `"1.1"` or `"1"` or `""` and from each of  them I need to get results in same format so it can be saved in SQL Db as numeric (8,2)

```
var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
            prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_ub_c", Decimal.Parse(p_ub_c.Text.Replace(',', '.') == string.Empty ? "0.00" : p_ub_c.Text, ci));
```

Passed string is: `"2500,00"` but can be also `""` or `"2500.00"`

Those values needs to be saved in sql numeric(8,2)
And when the textbox `p_ub_cis` empty then string is 0 and I got this: System.FormatException input string was not in correct format.

May someone help me solve this out?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense. How can 1.1, 1 and an empty string all yield the same result? What value do you want them to all equal?

Comment: Can we see the actual string passed to the `Decimal.Parse`?

Comment: @DavidArno Sorry I mean same formatted result.

Comment: According to your answer, you didn't understand me, I want you to show the evaluation of - `p_ub_c.Text.Replace(',', '.') == string.Empty ? "0.00" : p_ub_c.Text, ci`, You should not have `,` since you replaced them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies with the follow code fragment:

```
p_ub_c.Text.Replace(',', '.') == string.Empty ? "0.00" : p_ub_c.Text
```

This says 'take my Text and replace "," with ".", then if the result is an empty string, use "0.00", otherwise use Text'. In other words, you lose the result of the Replace.

If you change it to store the results of the Replace and parse that, it should fix the problem. Beware of someone entering eg "1,000.1" though as you'll end up with "1.000.1", which is still an invalid number.

Comment: @DavidAmo THank you but on Windows XP it cannot format. On my Windows 8 its ok. Dont you know how  to handle that please?

Comment: Sorry @Marek, but I don't understand. What cannot format on XP?

Comment: Your code formats well on Windows 8 but on Windows XP it says error converting nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: I haven't provided you with any code. I've quoted yours. You need to change it to that supplied by @Yosi in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You never use what `Replace` returns, you should use it as following:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_ub_c.Text) ? "0.00" : p_ub_c.Text.Replace(',', '.');
```